# Databricks DELTA CTAS with LOCATION using %sql

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

`DELTA` does not have `CREATE TABLE LIKE`. It does have `CTAS`.

I want to copy the *definition* of a table only, but also specify the `LOCATION`.

E.g. this does not work:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NEW_CUSTOMER_FEED 
AS SELECT * from NEW_CUSTOMER_FEED WHERE 1 = 0 
LOCATION '/atRest/data'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you check [syntax](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html#syntax) for `CREATE TABLE USING`, then you will see that `AS SELECT ...` should be the last clause, after all options.  So in your case it should be

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NEW_CUSTOMER_FEED 
LOCATION '/atRest/data'
AS SELECT * from NEW_CUSTOMER_FEED WHERE 1 = 0
```

P.S. Instead of `WHERE 1=0`, you can just do `LIMIT 0`...

Comment: Did not glean that from the manual. Thx